# Chat implementation using firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, chat

I have implemented chat application using firebase realtime database and it working fine. I have few more requirements to meet the complete functionality. Below is the requirement

1. Last entered message with date/time
2. No. of Unread message
3. While you are in the chat listing page showing or updating the counter with messages spontaneously when someone is sending you message
4. Sending push notification when a user send message

Is these possible using the firebase functionalities ?

Comment: you need to store every information in Realtime Database. Secondly for Push Notification you can use Cloud Functions By Firebase.

Comment: Yes it is possible but you need to manage data structure according to your requirement.

Comment: You can add custom functions in firebase. Refer to [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/)